# Handling wildcards with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to fetch the data from Facebook user table using wild cards. But, I guess current FQL is not supporting the wildcards, or I'm missing something.

Also, it gives an error for LIKE as well.

currently, I'm executing it as follow

SELECT uid, username,first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE '%ab%' order by first_name LIMIT 0,20;

I tried *, ?, _ etc.

Still, i couldn't get it yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to do something similar, but even then you can't ask such a question from the api.

Here's a "working" version of your query:

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name
FROM user
WHERE strpos(lower(first_name), 'ab') >= 0
ORDER BY first_name
LIMIT 0,20
```

The problem with this query is that it produces [this error](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20username%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20strpos%28lower%28first_name%29%2C%20%27ab%27%29%20%3E%3D%200%20order%20by%20first_name%20LIMIT%200%2C20%3B):

> Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked
>   from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

You basically don't have a way to ask for all users, just based on specific user(s), for example this works:

```
SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name
FROM user
WHERE strpos(lower(first_name), 'ab') >= 0 AND uid IN ("user_id_1", "user_id_2", ...,"user_id_n")
ORDER BY first_name
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: Thank you Nitzan. I basically have the same kind of query.

SELECT uid, username,first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and strpos(lower(first_name), 'ab') order by first_name LIMIT 0,20;

But still it is not giving the desired results. 'ab' or any other value doesn't have any effect.

Comment: You forgot the `>= 0` part, it should be: `SELECT uid, username,first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and strpos(lower(first_name), 'ab') >=0 ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 0,20;`

Answer (score 1):

[FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) doesn't support the LIKE operator. You can use the supported strpos function to perform partial string searches on supported table indices, however [none of the name fields on the user table are indexable](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2Cusername%2Cname%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20strpos%28first_name%2C%20%27ab%27%29%20%3E%3D0).